# Build router-link with global language parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a set of routes that look like this where the language is optional. If not set it will default to english:

- /search
- /nl/search/
- /de/search/

Now I want to generate the routes with a `router-link` element.

```
<router-link :to="{ 
    name: 'search-map', 
    params: { language: $language }
}">
    testlink
</router-link>
```

This works but the language is something I already have set globally in Vue. Obviously I would like to not pass in the param on the `router-link` all the time and have this be done automatically.

I have tried to use the navigation guards but this does not seem to work:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    to.params.language = Vue.prototype.$language;
    next();
});
```

Is there another way to get this done so I do not have to specify the language param on every `router-link`? Or is the navigation guard suppose to work?

Comment: Vue-router will inherit params from the current route, so you shouldn't need to specify the `language` param for every `<router-link>`.

Comment: My router links will not be generated properly though let's say I use this route path `path: '/:language?/:entity/',` then how is my `router-link` suppose to know how to generate a proper path for it without me having to manually set the `params` property on each `router-link` component?

Comment: Ok, the optional param `:language?` will not be inherited.

Comment: Alternatively, you could define all your routes as children of the route that is defined for the language

Comment: @Derek true but in my application the language `en` should default to a route of `/search/` instead of `/en/search/` this exceptions kind of forces me to use the navigation guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about if `to` does not contain param `language`, add it in `next()`

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!to.params.hasOwnProperty('language')) {
    next({
      ...to,
      params: {
        ...to.params,
        language: Vue.prototype.$language
      }
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Comment: This seems to work. I have tried something like this by setting the language directly on the `to` object but I guess you need to manually set it in `next`.

Comment: I'd opt for `language: from.params.language || Vue.prototype.$language` instead, but it depends on your requirements.